# Laravel framework at error on php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use `php artisan migrate` and I get the following error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1193 Unknown system variable
> 'sql_require_primary_key' (SQL: SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=0)

**Source code**
https://github.com/polusgg/website-accounts

Answer (score 1):

Two of the migrations have this line

```
DB::statement('SET SESSION sql_require_primary_key=0');
```

This is present to avoid an issue with Digital Ocean managed databases, where they do not permit a database to not have a primary key.

If you are not using Digital Ocean, comment these lines out.

- `database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php`
- `database/migrations/2014_10_12_200000_add_two_factor_columns_to_users_table.php`